# Session cookie not saving after app deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session, passport.js

I created a frontend application using React which I then deployed on Netlify. The frontend app interacts with my express backend application which I created and deployed to Render. Any interaction between the frontend and backend is protected by authentication using passportjs. The backend app uses passports local strategy to verify with a mongoDB connection if the user exists/username and password are correct. Once confirmed, I use passports serialize and deserialize functions to maintain a login session.

During development I worked through this application on http://localhost. During this time, everything worked as intended. The login session was saved as a cookie and I was able to send that through the frontend app as part of future requests to the backend app to authenticate the user.

When I deployed my frontend app to Netlify and backend app to Render, the session cookie no longer saved meaning the user could never be authenticated in the backend as every request, after logging in, had no saved session cookie to send along to the backend.

A little more detail, for the express-session, used in combination with passport to create the login session, I used connect-mongo to store the session on a MongoDB. Each time I login through the frontend, I can see the session being created and stored in MongoDB. The problem appears to be that the cookie is not being transferred over in the response from the backend and I am not sure why.

Here is the session options I currently have in my express backend app:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI }),
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: 24 * 60*60*1000
    }
  })
);
```

I have tried searching around to find a solution and have messed with many of the options including changing `secure`, changing `httpOnly`, setting `sameSite` to false and none, adding a `domain` which points to the frontend URL and another for the backend URL, removing any security packages that I installed such as helmet and a rate limiter and nothing seems to be working.

I have also set the access control header for credentials to true:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", process.env.DOMAIN_URL);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
  next();
});
```

For all my requests I am using `fetch`. I can across a similar problem to mine but it was not answered: [Browser not saving session cookie from cross domain server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879087/browser-not-saving-session-cookie-from-cross-domain-server)

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The issue was with trust proxy. Since I am running multiple domain servers, the backend was behind a reverse proxy. By enabling trust proxy, my backend app will understand that its sitting behind a proxy and the X-Forwarded- header fields may be trusted. To enable it I added the following code in my backend app:

```
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
```

This guide contains more info: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to that little lock icon placed on the left-hand side of the url in urlbar.
2. Select `Cookies and site data`.
3. Uncheck the `Block third-party cookies` option.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).